# Any way to change a listview header on top over scroll?

Tags: android, listview, header, overscroll

I want to change the text of the header when the user overscroll the listview in the top. Like a "Relase for refreshing" Is this posible?

Comment: add header in listview  and onscroll chnage lister you can edit the text in listview header

Comment: Maybe you are looking for SwipeRefreshLayout (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)

Comment: Yep, I've SwipeRefreshLayout already working fine, and if you overscroll the circle button apears and refresh right the app, but I don't know how to put an effect showing another text when you overscroll the listview.

Comment: @Diva I'll look for the onscrollchangelistener, thanks